# Assigning a surname to the list of cash deposits

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm working in Java and I have txt file, which contains nearly 700 000 lines and looks like this:

```
Kowalski
1500
Kowalski
1200
Smith
3200
Black
2200
Kowalski
1100
...
```

I need any data structure, which assign a surname to the list of cash deposits.

```
[Kowalski] => [1500, 1200, 1100, ...]
[Smith] => [3200, ...]
[Black] => [2200, ...]
```

I don't want reinvent the wheel, is there any data structure provided by Java?

Comment: Are you looking for `Map<String,List<Integer>>` ?

Comment: Better yet, `MultiMap`: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Map<String,List<Integer>>`:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    int deposit = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    List<Integer> deposits = map.get(name);
    if(deposits == null) {
        deposits = new ArrayList<>();
        map.put(name, deposits);
    }
    deposits.add(deposit);
}
```